# How do I use Join in MySQLi php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have databases called Over_Pics (with a table called "Pic" with Columns ID, PicID) and Over_SeenPics (with a table called "Seen" with Columns Text, PicID)

How do I correctly write the join function for this?

```
$r = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Pic.PicID FROM Pic LEFT JOIN Seen ON Pic.PicID=Seen.PicID");
```

Also should the db name in mysqil_connect be left blank, since I need to access to dbs rather than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the DB before the table names, like this:

```
$r = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Over_Pics.Pic.PicID FROM Over_Pics.Pic LEFT JOIN Over_SeenPics.Seen ON Over_Pics.Pic.PicID=Over_SeenPics.Seen.PicID");
```

You can loop through the rows of the result set with this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        echo $key." - ".$value.", ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

That will output the results of the query to the screen.  Of course you will most likely want to change the formatting.

Comment: true but `Over_Pics.Pic.PicI`D can be `Pic.PicID` as long as its only one table named Pic in the `FROM`

Comment: actually I think I got it, but how do I print out the resulting rows from this? thanks!